# Lemon sweet yeast bread

Tags: bread

Can I mix up dough today, refridgerate overnight in bowl, then bring to room temperature and continue the rising, shaping the next day?

Comment: Yes, and there are quite a few comprehensive answers and links here http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/63071